# Call Async Api using rxSwift and alamofire, the view show up more quickly than getting api response

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I have a problem about updating View with async Api.
How to prevent this situation and make sure the label isn't nothing.
It makes me the label to be nothing to show.
Thanks.

Update Code:

```
var memberCount:String = ""

func updateNavigation() {

    navigationItem.titleView = setTitleWitImage(title: self.name + "(" + self.memberCount + ")", titleImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "titleImage"))
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    var parameters:[String:Any] = [String:Any]()
    parameters["id"] = self.id

    API.member.get( parameters,{ json in

        guard json.isEmpty == false else {

            print("nulllllllllllll")
            return
        }

        let number:Int = json.count
        self.memberCount = String(number)
        print("*\(self.memberCount)")

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            self.updateNavigation()
        })
    })
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    //updateNavigation()
}
```

Sorry, I use @Sandeep Bhandari answer, it will make another problem about my Navigation Title.
I record my problem video here.

> [Problem Video here Thanks!!!](https://youtu.be/sJJhOwSSEK8)

Answer (score 0):

```
API.member.get( parameters,{ json in

        guard json.isEmpty == false else {

            print("nulllllllllllll")
            return
        }

        let number:Int = json.count
        self.memberCount = String(number)
        self.updateNavigation()
    })
```

This should solve your problem

Reason : get is a async call and viewDidAppear gets called even before get receives the response. Hence once get receives the response update UI

Comment: Thanks you, but I get another problem. @Sandeep Bhandari